# C# task repeat every x count

Tags: c#

There are currently many solutions on StackOverflow using C# task to repeatedly do some work every x time interval. I would like to do it repeatedly to say every 100 counts of a counter. This counter is not time-based but is actually a number of values stored into an array for example. Is there any tutorial which could give an idea on how to implement this?

Comment: *Gimme teh tutorialz* is not a valid question for stackoverflowz

Comment: Try using TaskScheduler Class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Afonso This is terrible advice. The name "TaskScheduler" sounds good, but it actually doesn't do what you might think it does. This is used for scheduling tasks internally to thread pool. There is absolutely no reason to call this class.

Comment: @TheGeneral Maybe not tutorial but some direction. I feel that the Task class in C# is very useful especially for data acquisition but instead of time based, a counter based would be also equally useful if we wanted to do analysis say every 1000 samples regardless of how long the data took.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this ?

```
if (i%100 == 0)
{
   // do something
}
```